# Trouble with adding multiple values into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to learn more about arrays and so I just wrote this simple function:
(I'm calling `doThis` from an `onClick` for testing purposes).

```
function doThis() {
    var multiplier = 3;
    var list = [23, 54, 23, 25, 65];
    var products = multiply(list, multiplier);
    console.log(products);
}
function multiply(list, multiplier) {
    list.forEach(function (element){
        var multi = [element * multiplier];
        console.log(multi);
        return multi;
    });
}
```

My issue is two-fold:

1. `var products` is returning `undefined`.
2. When I step through the code in the debugger, it shows the arithmetic being done correctly, but it doesn't store more than one value in the variable `multi`.

The end goal would be to have `var products` hold the `multi` array.

Comment: You should push multiplied item to some array, which you can return after looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function doThis() {
    var multiplier = 3
    var list = [23, 54, 23, 25, 65]
    var products = multiply(list, multiplier)
    console.log(products)
}

function multiply(list, multiplier) {
var multi = [] ;
list.forEach(
   function (element){
       multi.push(element * multiplier)
       console.log(multi)
       //return multi
   }
);
return multi ;
}
```

Comment: Refer this one::

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()` When you are planning to return a new array from an existing array. `forEach()` let you iterate the array but doesn't return any new array.

```js
function doThis() {
    var multiplier = 3;
    var list = [23, 54, 23, 25, 65];
    var products = multiply(list, multiplier);
    console.log(products);
}
function multiply(list, multiplier) {
   return list.map(function (element){
        return element * multiplier;
    });
}

doThis();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple points here:

1. the function *multiply()* is not returning the return from `list.forEach()`. Add the [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) keyword before `list.forEach(function (element){`
2. [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

> #### Return value
>
> [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)
>   <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value)</sup>

To return the result from each iteration, use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or manually add each return value to the array.

See the changes in the snippet below.

To learn more about map() and similar functions, try [these exercises](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/).

```js
function doThis() {
  var multiplier = 3
  var list = [23, 54, 23, 25, 65]
  var products = multiply(list, multiplier)
  console.log('products: ', products)
}

function multiply(list, multiplier) {
  return list.map(
    function(element) {
      var multi = [element * multiplier]
      return multi
    }
  );
}
document.getElementById('doThis').addEventListener('click', doThis);
```

```html
<button id="doThis">doThis()</button>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Using `return` in a `forEach` function on an array will not change the values of the original array.

You need to specify where you want to set a value. I suggest using the second parameter in the `forEach` anonymous function, being the index of the element.

Then you can easily do `list[index] = "my new value";`

Also, putting the value of the multiplying action between brackets (you did `var multi = [element * multiplier];`) creates a single-element array for each value.

Here's how I did it to keep a one dimension array:

```js
function doThis() {
    var multiplier = 3
    var list = [23, 54, 23, 25, 65]
    var products = multiply(list, multiplier)
    console.log(products)
}

function multiply(list, multiplier) {
    list.forEach(function(element, index) {
        list[index] = element * multiplier
    });

    return list;
}

doThis();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop while you're learning about arrays:

```
function multiply(list, multiplier) {
    var multi = [];
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        multi.push(list[i] * multiplier)
    }

    return multi;
}
```